# SCSS : Import variable and style rule from another file. I don't want duplication style rule

Tags: css, sass

I don't really understand about `@import` and `partial file`
But I want to ask for a little understanding.

I have 2 files. file2.scss must use the variable from file1.scss.

File1.scss

```
/* file1.scss */
$color-1 : #7E3D97;

@font-face{
    font-family : AngsanaNew;
    src: url(/font/AngsanaNew.TTF);
}

div.test1{
     background-color: #222;
}
```

File2.scss

```
/* file2.scss */
@import 'file1'

div.content{
    background-color : $color-1;
}
```

When I compile SCSS, It generates 2 files. Which is not what I want. I want it to be

```
/* file1.css */    
@font-face{
    font-family : AngsanaNew;
    src: url(/font/AngsanaNew.TTF);
}

div.test1{
     background-color: #222;
}
```

AND

```
/* file2.css */        
div.content{
    background-color : #7E3D97;
}
```

Because if I want to create a file `file3.css`, `file4.css`. while there is already a file1.css style rule. I will see `@font-face` and `div.test1` contain in `file3.css`, `file4.css`.

I don't want that. What should I do?

P.S. Sorry my english. If you edit my text to make it easy to read. I will be very grateful.

Comment: Can you put here the 2 files that it generate?

Answer (score 0):

If SASS is generating the CSS it does it for every 'normal named' `file.scss`. To mark a file for SASS that it should not be used to generate a separate css file use an underscore `_` as prefix, - i.e. `_partial.scss`. That files will only be used to be imported to the main scss file.

Now you can organize your project:

```
// POSSIBLE PROJECT STRUCURE

// variables to whole project
// --> variables only, no classes
_defaults.scss 

// partial files
// --> use vairables from _default.scss
// --> or if you want/need to define variables here 
// --> use variables with default-flag: '$variable: value !default' 
// --> so they will/can be overwritten by same variable set BEFORE in _default.scss
_partial-structure.scss
_partial-element.scss
...

// bring them together in main file

styles.scss
   @import 'defaults';
   @import 'partial-structure';
   @import 'partial-element';
   ...
```